# Como alterar o ícone do executável gerado de um produto E4 RCP?

Tags: eclipse

Tenho uma aplicação *standalone* em Eclipse 4 RCP.

Ao exportar ela como um produto, conforme imagem a seguir:

[image: Wizard de exportação de produto Eclipse]

Gera-se a estrutura a seguir:

[image: Estrutura gerada]

Como alterar o ícone do executável aplicacao.exe? Eu já tentei colocar imagens na aba Launching do arquivo .product, porém sem sucesso.

[image: Imagens launching do arquivo .product]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu estava com dois problemas:

1. Meu arquivo **`.ico`** não estava sendo aceito pelo Eclipse, então eu peguei o ícone do Eclipse, abri no **GIMP** e troquei suas respectivas imagens/camadas para as minhas em **formato PNG**. Ao exportar, **desmarquei todas as opções para comprimir as imagens**. Defini uma imagem para os tamanhos **16x16**, **32x32**, **48x48** e **256x256**; como **32 bits e canal alfa de 8 bits**; além de uma imagem para os tamanhos **16x16**, **32x32** e **48x48**; como **8 bits e canal alfa de 1 bit**;
2. O processo de exportação do meu produto estava pegando o ícone da última exportação e não o que eu defini. Então eu alterei o **Launcher Name** na aba **Launching** do arquivo **`.product`**, o que fez com que o cache fosse atualizado e o novo ícone fosse utilizado.

**OBS:** Para o segundo problema, atualizar o cache de ícones do sistema operacional já resolve.